# Can I use Keras to give fitness scores to a genetic algorithm?

Tags: neural-network, keras, python-3.x, genetic-programming

I know that I can use Keras to solve classification problems but is it possible to get it to output a float between 0 and 1000 for instance? I want train my network to approximate the simulation that gives my GA a fitness score because the simulation takes a long time to run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get a neural network to predict real numbers instead of for classification. This type of problem is called **regression**.

You can find dozens of tutorials for doing regression with Keras. The official one is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression).